# Why is Netezza using materialized view in explain plan

Tags: sql, netezza, materialized-views

I have a materialized view in Netezza that is on 5 columns in my Customer table. I wrote a query that includes a column (Customer_email) from Customer that is NOT in the materialized view, and when I do Explain Plain on the query, it shows just the materialized view, not the Customer table at all, which I don't understand. Does anyone have an explanation for this?

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW CUSTOMER_DIM_MV
AS
SELECT 
    customer_key,
    persona_key,
    customer_birthdate,
    customer_zip,   
    update_datetime 
FROM 
    CUSTOMER_DIM
ORDER BY customer_key;


select 
  customer_key
, customer_birthdate
, customer_email
from (
select base.customer_key,
      cd.customer_birthdate,  
      cd.customer_email,
      row_number() over (partition by base.customer_key order by cd.update_datetime desc) trans_date
from extract_base base
join CUSTOMER_DIM cd on base.customer_key = cd.customer_key
) a
where a.trans_date = 1;

Sub-query Scan table "A" (cost=7881.4..7881.4 rows=1956474 width=11 conf=80)
   l: Aggregate (cost=7881.4..7881.4 rows=1956474 width=23 conf=0)
      l: Hash Join (cost=9.9..7870.8 rows=1956474 width=18 conf=64)
         l: Sequential Scan mview index  "_MCUSTOMER_DIM_MV" (cost=0.0..6867.3 rows=13132953 width=16 conf=80) 
         r: Hash (cost=5.1..5.1 rows=669425 width=8 conf=0)
            l: Sequential Scan table "BASE" (cost=0.0..5.1 rows=669425 width=8 conf=100)
```

Comment: The optimizer may choose to read the MV and base table both. Clearly here it *must* read the base table to return customer email.  Look through the rest of the plan and you should find a reference to the base table

Comment: And here when I say "base" i mean the base table for the MV (customer_dim), not the extract_base table

Comment: In the "Verbose" version of the plan it also doesn't reference the base table either. If I do run a query that doesn't have ANY columns from the MV, it will show the actual table, at least.

Comment: What does the actual execution plan show?  If you run the query, and immediately run "show planfile;" after it?

Comment: oh I didn't know or think to do "show planfile"- I've just been clicking the "Explain" button in Aginity like a newb. So that is what I'm looking for! Lots more detail in that and it did show the base table, customer_dim, getting used. You can add as an answer if you want and I'd accept it

Comment: If you have netezza host access then please take out the plan id and run nz_plan <plan_id> and provide the output . Ideally in this case Optimizer should choose base table of the MV rather than the MV .